# Почему не находит папку C#?

Tags: c#

Вот метод:

```
private FileInfo[] GetCachedFiles(string directoryPath)
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
    if (!directory.Exists)
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Не найдена директория кэша");

    var files = directory.GetFiles("*.json");
    if (files.Length == 0)
        return null;

    return files;
}
```

Он не может найти директорию Cache, хотя я создал ее, я не понимаю в чем причина. В параметре передается относительный путь `"Cache"`.[image: Картинка]

Comment: Не вижу вызова данного метода и не вижу пути, который задается в `directoryPath`. Ставьте точку остановки и смотрите какие значения вы там получаете и соответствуют-ли они действительности.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я ведь написал какой путь передается.

Comment: Реальное запускаемое приложение может находиться в совершенно другой папке (и скорее всего она рядом с проектом) и отсюда не факт, что вы создали папку Cache в нужном месте. Тем более если не указали, что она должна так же копироваться вместе с файлами компиляции в конечную папку.

Comment: Повторю, ставьте точку остановки и сверяйте данные с тем, что ожидаете. Поставьте точку остановки на `if (!directory.Exists)` и смотрите какой путь у вас прописан в `var directory` (свойство `FullName`), ну а потом попробуйте скопировать этот путь и посмотрите, есть-ли он у вас на диске. Касательно "я ведь написал" - я это предложение воспринимаю как "Указал путь до этой папки", то есть не просто `Cache`, а что-то иное, но это ладно, пусть будет моя невнимательность...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо писать кеш в папку с приложением. Пишите его в папку для временных файлов.

За местонахождение этой папки отвечает переменная окружения `%TMP%`. Временных файлов не должно быть там, где у вас постоянные.

Получить путь к временной директории можно так.

```
private static readonly string cachePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyAppCache");
```

Получится примерно такой путь `C:\Users\<User_Name>\AppData\Local\Temp\MyAppCache`

При обращении к кешу, просто делайте так

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(cachePath);
```

При этом, не нужно проверять `directory.Exists` так как метод `CreateDirectory` если каталог не существует, он его создаст, а если существует, то вернет путь к существующему.

```
private FileInfo[] GetCachedFiles()
{
    var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(cachePath);

    var files = directory.GetFiles("*.json");
    if (files.Length == 0)
        return null;

    return files;
}
```

Дополнительный плюс такого подхода в том, что даже если вы перемещаете прилижение или меняются другие условия доступа к каталогу приложения, например запрет на запись в каталог с приложением, ваш кеш продолжит работать нормально.

Записать объект в кеш можно примерно так

```
public Task SaveCacheAsync<T>(string fileName, T data)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(cachePath, fileName);
    using var fs = File.Create(path);
    return JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(fs, data);
}
```

```
await SaveCacheAsync("file.json", data);
```